# Div Contents on one line?

Tags: html, overflow

How do I get the contents of my DIV to all stay on one line?
I've seen other posts, but I can figure out what I'm doing wrong?

here is a link to the page with an issue:
http://www.heatx.org/productcart/pc/viewCategories.asp?idCategory=2

Comment: We're going to need more information about what your goal is, what you've tried, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your link start by adding `float: left;` to `#pcIconBarRight img` and `#pcIconBar a`. This should address your question.

EDIT:

Then change this:

[image]

And this:
[image]

EDIT2:
To display two divs in one row you could do this:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
    <div style="float: left; clear: none;">Total:&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="float: left; clear: none;">159 USD</div>
</div>
```

Note: the `width: 200px;` you should set the width big enough for the inner div's to fit, otherwise it will break the second div to the next line.

Comment: Esteban, you were really helpful; its mostly working now with the exception of the following: when you add an item to the cart, a line drops down and displays "Total: $x.xx", I'd like to have it all on one line?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is due to the images inside the div. Set `display:inline` to those images.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this into your bottom of css file

```
table{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

to align your site in center

your menu is not appeared !

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late for answering OP's question. This will be useful for other people having the same problem.

So to get all the elements to appear on a single line the easiest way is:

1. Set **white-space: nowrap;overflow-x: auto;** on the parent element.
2. Set **display: inline-block**  on all child elements.

Result:
[image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs8e4j2f/4/)

```
 <div style="width:100%;white-space:nowrap;overflow-x:auto;border: 1px solid red; border-radius: 10px;padding: 3px;">
   <label style="display: inline-block">Some label </label>
  <select style="display: inline-block">
    <option value="0">aaaaa</option>
    <option value="1">bbbbbb</option>
    <option value="2">ccccccccc</option>
  </select>
  <label style="display: inline-block">Another label: </label>
  <input type="text" style="display: inline-block;width:200px;" />
  <span style="display: inline-block">NOTE: some other text</span>
</div>
```